# last element in header menu can't be formatted properly

Tags: html, css

If you visit a website I am working on [foramtionMTL](http://formationmtl.com/index.php) on firefox, you will notice that the background of the last element in the header menu "CONTACT US" doesn't span the entire length of the field.

Why is that? and how can I fix it?

HTML:

```
 <div class="headmenus">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="search.php">COURSES</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacancies.php">VACANCIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>    
    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.headmenus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0086B2;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.headmenus ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'texgyreadventorregular';
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.headmenus ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 19.895%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.headmenus ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'texgyreadventorregular';
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
}
.headmenus ul li:hover {
    background: #89ab20;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headmenus ul li.active {
    background: #89ab20;
}
headmenus ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 0 none;
        float: right;
    width: 19.9%; !important
}
```

Comment: `echo $home;` etc....what is this `echo`ing..is it some class???

Comment: yes it's just for selection of the active menu, not important.. will remove from post

Comment: Why not set `width: 19.895%;` to `20%`? on the `.headmenus li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting in your `width` value this:

```
.headmenus ul li {
   width:19.895%;
}
```

Change it to 20% then the five items can be full 100% of the parent:

```
.headmenus ul li {
   width:20%;
}
```

In addition include `box-sizing` for all browsers you only include that for `-moz-` prefix:

```
.headmenus ul li {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: And now check in chrome, you will see the unwanted effect.

Comment: @Sachin and now check the addition of `box-sizing`

Comment: @Danko yes now it looks fine +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your css selector for the last element. It says `headmenus ul li:last-child {` instead of `.headmenus ul li:last-child {`. If you fix that you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you but that was a bug only to this post :)

Comment: @Kam I didn't look in your post, I looked at the css in Firefox dev tool on your page, so it was there as well.

Comment: Yes Yes, I agree it was a bug introduced 5 min ago :)
when I fixed it nothing changed

Comment: Weird, because for me those extra styling lines did as I read them: remove the right border, float it to the right (hiding the gap) and increasing the width.  
Before: http://s27.postimg.org/isa7kjzhv/before.png
After: http://s18.postimg.org/aqwgmydnt/after.png

Answer (score 0):

```
.headmenus ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Try this